# How expensive is the Extended Euclidean Algorithm?

Tags: rsa, modular-arithmetic, factoring

Given a [private key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) $k$ and a [modulus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic) $n=pq$, where $p \neq q$ are two *very* large prime numbers, we find the value of [Euler's Totient Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_totient_function) $\varphi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$. The public key $K$ is given by the [multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse) of the private key, modulo $\varphi(n)$, i.e. $kK \equiv 1 \bmod \varphi(n)$.This is often written as $K = k^{-1} \pmod{\varphi(n)}$.

The [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) can by used to find $K$. Assuming that $k$ and $\varphi(n)$ are coprime, i.e. $\gcd(k,\varphi(n))=1$, [we can find integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout's_identity) $s$ and $t$ for which $ks + \varphi(n)t=1$. The multiplicative inverse of $k$, i.e. the public key $K$, will be given by $s$.

Assuming that $n=pq$ is a very large number, say 1024 bit or larger, it follows that $\varphi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$ will also be a very large number.

**How "expensive" is it, or how long would it take, to compute the multiplicative inverse of $k \pmod{\varphi(n)}$ using the extended Euclidean algorithm? How does this "expense"/time compare to factorise $n$?**

Comment: If you know $k$ and $\varphi(n)$, computing  the multiplicative inverse of $k$ $\pmod{\varphi(n)}$ is only a few times more costly than division of $\varphi(n)$ by $k$; that is, in practice, inexpensive. It you only know $k$ and $n$,  computing  the multiplicative inverse of $k$ $\pmod{\varphi(n)}$ is about as hard as factoring $n$.

Comment: The fact that **the EEA is cheap** (or equivalently, that computing GCDs and modular inverses is easy) is absolutely fundamental, and you should look into it seriously with a good computational number theory textbook.

Comment: By the way, if you only know the modulus $n$, then the EEA is irrelevant since you do not know $\varphi(n)$ (so you cannot run the EEA on it).

Comment: @fkraiem But I'm the private key holder, so I  know $p$ and $q$ where $n=pq$.

Comment: Right, then the previous comment applies.

Answer (score 2):

If you have two positive integers $a>b>0$ with $n_1,n_2$ bits respectively, you need
$O(n_1n_2)$ running time to compute integers $d,s,t$ such that $d=\gcd(a,b)$ and $d=as+bt$ (this is theorem 4.4 of Victor Shoup book). In your case (since you know $\phi(N))$ set $a=K, b=\phi(N)$ to compute $k$ (as you desrcibed) in time $O( len(\phi((N))\cdot len(k) ).$

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What is $\operatorname{len}(k)$?

Comment: the binary length.

Comment: Thanks for that. What would the running time for the factorisation of $n$ be in terms of $\operatorname{len}(p)$ and $\operatorname{len}(q)$, where $n=pq$, be?

Comment: If you have as input the private and public key and you want to factor N, there is a probabilistic polynomial algorithm which will give you the factors with probability ≈1/2. Is that you want?

Comment: Let's say I'm a public key holder (so I know the modulus $n$ and public key $K$). How hard is it to factorise $n$? The motivation for my question is (quite naively): using RSA is "easy" and uses the EEA which depends on division of very large numbers, but the "hard" problem of factorising is also a division problem. What is the relative difficulty of using the EEA to find the public key $K = k^{-1} \pmod{\varphi(n)}$ compared to factoring $n$ given $K$?

Comment: Very hard if you choose $n$ large enough (>2048 bits). The best algorithm (untill today) is the number field sieve ( heuristically subexpoential bit complexity). You can find many good articles for this algorithm. Remark that, to find inverses $\mod n$ is very easy (polynomial bit complexity).